# what is the best way to get post data in nodejs not express?

Tags: node.js

I am using nodejs write a simple http proxy server.when I wanna get the post data,I found out there was no best method unless using express. please tell me the way using the nodejs only, to get the post data the right way.

here is the bad one found:

```
...
    req.setEncoding('utf-8')
    req.addListener("data", function (postDataChunk) {
        postData += postDataChunk;
    });
    req.addListener("end", function () {

        var objectPostData = querystring.parse(postData);

        console.log(objectPostData)
    });
....
```

Comment: With vanilla node that's the way to do it. Or you can use a higher abstraction framework like express...

Comment: not bad, if you don't want to use any frameworks

Comment: It is not bad one...It is raw post data handling code for node.js ``request``. All the frameworks do this internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple [bl](https://github.com/rvagg/bl) (BufferList) module to collect all chunks into one buffer:

```
var bl = require('bl');

...

req.pipe(bl(function (err, data) {
   console.log('POST data: ' +  data.toString());
}));
```